# Разместить кнопку под блоком с телефоном

Tags: html, css, blocks

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне приподнять блок с телефоном и кнопкой, я пробовал через margin-top: -46. Но уверен, что так неправильно и вряд ли это правильно. Вот код:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
 
}
 
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
 
.clearfix:after {
    content:'';
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.container{
    width: 1230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
 
#header{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 
.wrapper__logo{
    padding-top: 11px;  
    float: left;
    margin-right: 51px;
}
 
.wrapper__navbar{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
 
.wrapper__menu{
    float: left;
    margin: 42px 18px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
}
 
.wrapper__menu a {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 
.wrapper__menu a:hover{
    height: 37px;
    width: 172px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #f7f2fe;
}
 
.wrapper__phone{
    margin-top: -46px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    float: right;
    color: #2f1059;
}
 
.wrapper__phone a {
    margin-top: 12px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #2f1059;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #2f1059;
    padding: 12px 4px 13px 30px;
}
```

```html
    <section id="header" class="clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper__logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper__navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Инфраструктура
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Планировки и цены
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Материалы и отделка
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Документы
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Контакты
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper__phone">
                    <p>+7 (495) 544-23-12</p>
                    <a href="#">
                        Заказать звонок
                    </a>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `position: relative;`

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
 
}
 
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
 
.clearfix:after {
    content:'';
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.container{
    width: 1230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
 
#header{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 
.wrapper__logo{
    padding-top: 11px;  
    float: left;
    margin-right: 51px;
}
 
.wrapper__navbar{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
 
.wrapper__menu{
    float: left;
    margin: 42px 18px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
}
 
.wrapper__menu a {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 
.wrapper__menu a:hover{
    height: 37px;
    width: 172px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #f7f2fe;
}
 
.wrapper__phone{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    float: right;
    color: #2f1059;
}
 
.wrapper__phone a {
    margin-top: 12px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #2f1059;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #2f1059;
    padding: 12px 4px 13px 30px;
}
```

```html
    <section id="header" class="clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper__logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper__navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Инфраструктура
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Планировки и цены
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Материалы и отделка
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Документы
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wrapper__menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                Контакты
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper__phone">
                    <p>+7 (495) 544-23-12</p>
                    <a href="#">
                        Заказать звонок
                    </a>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper__logo {
  padding-top: 11px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 51px;
}

.wrapper__navbar {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper__menu {
  float: left;
  margin: 42px 18px 0px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper__menu a {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper__menu a:hover {
  height: 37px;
  width: 172px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f7f2fe;
}

.wrapper__phone {
  margin-top: -46px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  float: right;
  color: #2f1059;
}

.wrapper__phone a {
  margin-top: 12px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #2f1059;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #2f1059;
  padding: 12px 4px 13px 30px;
}

.header__contacts {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 17px;
}

.contacts__phone {
  display: block;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2f1059;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.contacts__button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #2f1059;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #2f1059;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

.contacts__icon {
  background-image: url(http://preview.ibb.co/dE8do7/phone.png);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section id="header" class="clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper__logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper__navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="wrapper__menu">
            <a href="#">
                                Инфраструктура
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="wrapper__menu">
            <a href="#">
                                Планировки и цены
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="wrapper__menu">
            <a href="#">
                                Материалы и отделка
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="wrapper__menu">
            <a href="#">
                                Документы
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="wrapper__menu">
            <a href="#">
                                Контакты
                            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="header__contacts">
        <div class="contacts clearfix">
          <p class="contacts__phone">+7 (495) 544-23-12</p>
          <a href="#" class="contacts__button">
            <i class="contacts__icon">
                      
                    </i>
            <span class="contacts__text">Заказать звонок</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```